# Asp Net MVC 5 refresh a table in a partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So i ran into a little problem and i am having a hard time understanding what I should do to get the result I want/need.

So my application is supposed to show the route a certain object made in the last 2 hours. When the user loads the app they see several points scattered through out the map and when they click on one of those objects the route it made in the last 2 hours is shown, and a table I have is supposed to be updated with those coordinates. Now I make the call to fill the partial view when I get all the locations the object went to in the controller method.

this is how I start all of this (when the user clicks a point the following is executed)

(I am using openlayers 3 but it is irrelevant to this question)

```js
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '/Controller/GetRoutes',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (result) {
                alert('Added');
              
                var layerLines = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        features: [
                            new ol.Feature({
                                geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(routes, 'XY'),
                                name: 'Line'
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                });

                         
                map.addLayer(layerLines);             
            

          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              //some errror, some show err msg to user and log the error  
              alert(xhr.responseText);
  
          }
      });
```

So as you can see from this code the method GetRoutes() is going to be responsible for getting the information on where the object has been to.

This is the controller (I omitted most of the code thats responsible for drawing the actual routes since its quite a bit chunky)

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetRoutes()
    {

    var lastpoints = get an arraylist with all the points I want

   var name = get the name of the object 

    RouteInformation(lastPoints,name);

    return Json(lastPoints, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

I know I should probably change something here but i do not know what.
The method that gives me the last points is not mine, but I am required to use it so I have no other choice but to accept the arrayList it returns to me.

this is the RouteInformation method

```
 public ActionResult RouteInformation(ArrayList routeList, string name )
       {

           List<ObjPoint> routes = routeList.OfType<ObjPoint>().ToList();

           List<ObjRoute> objRoutes = new List<ObjRoute>();

           objRoutes.Add(new ObjRoute()
                         {

                             name = name,
                             ObjPoints = routes
                          });

           return PartialView("RouteDetailsView", objRoutes);
       }
```

My issue is updating/refreshing that table, I have it in a partial view but I have no idea on what I have to do in order update that table with the information I want to display (i can get that information I just can´t seem to show it).

ObjPoint is composed of latitude,longitude, date, time.

This is the ObjRoute model

```
 public class ObjRoute
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public  List<ObjPoint> ObjPoints { get; set; }      

}
```

And now the Views ...

this is how the "main view" calls the partial view

```html
<div> 
@Html.Partial("routeDetailsView")
</div>
```

And this is my partial view

```html
@model webVesselTracker.Models.ObjRoute

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RouteDetailsView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div>

    <table id="routeTable" class="table">
        <tr>
            
            <th>
               Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Latitude
            </th>
   <th>
                Longitude
            </th>
         
            <th></th>
        </tr>       

@if (Model != null) {

    foreach (var item in Model.ObjPoints)
    {
        
            <tr>      
                <td>                  
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Latitude)
                </td>
    <td>                  
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Longitude)
                </td>          
               
            </tr>
}
}

else
{
    <tr>
        <td>
          No object has been selected, please select one
        </td>

    </tr>
}
    </table>

</div>
```

Now I know I could probably do this by adding some sort of json request in the js file and from there on build the table, but I would like to know how to do this with Razor and where I have gone wrong in the code/logic.
Am I supposed to add some ajax elsewhere?

So to summarize this:

```
-User sees points. 
-User clicks point to see the route it made. 
-App draws the route and then sends the route information to a method  table so it can be added to the table
the user can see that information
```

Thank you for your time and if I missed something please point it out so I can fix or explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up and looked into knockout.js, it managed to solve all the issues I was having

[knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Comment: have a look at AngularJS too! If you are in the beginning phase of using knockout, it might be a good idea to take AngularJS instead.